# Show echoed messages during the execution of script

Tags: php

I would like to output some messages during the script execution, but it shows only after the end of execution. I tried some solutions here, but it seems they don't work for me, even I copied their solutions and copied theme in separate file and made the test, but same result.
Here is an example of one of the solutions I tried: How do I output contents in browser while the script is running?

My environment:

Windows 7, EasyPHP 14.1, PHP 5.3

Windows 2008 server, EasyPHP 14.1, PHP 5.3

Comment: It's probably an output buffer which collects the output and only prints it when a certain amount has accumulated.

Comment: @Jost Can I disable this?

Comment: can you paste your script ?

Answer (score 0):

This one was tough but somehow managed to get it working.

I don't have the same config as you, so that might not work...

```
 <?php
ini_set('zlib.output_handler', '');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('output_handler', '');
ini_set('output_buffering', false); 
ini_set('implicit_flush', true); 
apache_setenv( 'no-gzip', '1' );


for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    echo str_repeat(chr(0), 4096); #flood apache some null bytes so it feels the packet is big enough to be sent...
    echo "$i<br/>";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Comment: can you please show me the response headers you get?

Comment: Just this: `0
1
2
3
4`

Comment: Is that what you mean by "response headers"?

Comment: no, I mean HTTP response headers. Google it maybe. You can have it with your browser, check console (F12)